# How to check if user doesn't write anything in 4 seconds?

Tags: ios, swift, function, uitextview, nstimer

I have the next function:

```
override func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    super.textViewDidChange(textView)

    if textView.text.characters.count == 0 {
        print("stopped")
    } else {
        print("typing")
    }
}
```

So, I want the next:

For example, user is typing something and stopped in the middle of text. I want to check, if user wrote something and stopped in the middle of typing for 4 seconds to run the function `stopped()`.

I did this:

```
override func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    super.textViewDidChange(textView)

    if textView.text.characters.count == 0 {
        print("stopped")
    } else {
        print("typing")
        let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4.0, target: self, selector: "stopped", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}

func stopped() {
    print("stopped typing")
}
```

but it runs my NSTimer every time. That's not what I want.

How can I run it just one time? For example to check if user didn't write anything in 4 seconds to run `stopped()`. Just one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop the previous timer with [invalidate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/invalidate)

```
var timer
override func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    super.textViewDidChange(textView)

    if textView.text.characters.count == 0 {
        print("stopped")
    } else {
        timer.invalidate()
        print("typing")
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4.0, target: self, selector: "stopped", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to keep a reference on your timer and invalidate it whenever textViewDidChange is called, something like that :

```
var textViewTimer : NSTimer?
override func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    super.textViewDidChange(textView)
    textViewTimer.invalidate()
    if textView.text.characters.count == 0 {
        print("stopped")
    } else {
        print("typing")
        textViewTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4.0, target: self, selector: "stopped", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}

func stopped() {
    print("stopped typing")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for Swift 5

```swift
var textViewTimer: Timer?
override func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    textViewTimer.invalidate()
    print("typing")
    textViewTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4.0, target: self, selector: #selector(typingStopped), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
} 
@objc func typingStopped() {
    print("stopped")
}
```